# For the given the two sequences, I am getting a error for input while writing a program to combine two sequences and arrange them alphabetically?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def all_people(people_1, people_2):
    # update logic here
    people_1.split(',')
    people_2.split(',')
    people_1.extend(people_2)
    print(people_1.sort())

people_1 = input()
people_2 = input()

all_people(people_1, people_2)
```

For the given the two sequences, I am getting a AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'extend'
The problem is :how to write a program to combine two sequences and arrange them alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you input your list into `people_1` it becomes a **string**.
So for example, if you input `['Person 1', 'Person 2']` into `people_1`, then `people_1 = "['Person 1', 'Person 2']"`(A string). So in order to apply `.extend()` to `people_1` you first have to turn it into a **list**.

Try this:

```
import ast

people_1 = ast.literal_eval(input())
people_2 = ast.literal_eval(input())
```

(Be sure to import **ast**)

That way your input will automatically be changed from a string to a list and you can apply `.extend`.

Answer (score 0):

`str.split` will not transform the split string into a list (even without the type difference, strings are immutable), but *return* a list. To use it, you will need to assign it to a variable. If you don't need the original string, you can just overwrite it<sup>1</sup>.

```
list_1 = input('first list, separated by , -> ')
list_1 = list_1.split(',')
list_2 = input('second list, separated by , -> ').split(',')

list_1.extend(list_2)
print(list_1)
```

Will result in

```
first list, separated by , -> a,b,some value with spaces
second list, separated by , -> in,the,second,one
['a', 'b', 'some value with spaces', 'in', 'the', 'second', 'one']
```

---

<sup>1</sup> This applies to a simple case where you convert a data structure once. Don't go around overwriting variables with totally unrelated stuff all over the place.